# redirect directory to domain htaccess without changing domain url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site sub.domain1.com

But i would like to access to it from the following url: domain2.com/folder

Here is the .htaccess file in domain2.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) http://sub.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirection works well but i wouldn't like to change the url to sub.domain1.com

I want to display the content of sub.domain1.com by using the url domain2.com/folder without changing url.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you own both domains, and are they on the same server?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849066/redirecting-without-changing-url?rq=1

Comment: yes I'm the owner of both domain, and they are on the same srver.

Comment: What's the reason you can't move the files from sub.domain1.com inside a folder in domain2.com?

Comment: there's too many absolute links in the sub.domain1.com, so if we transfer the content from sub.domain1.com to domain2.com/folder, this will generate errors on both sub-domains.
So, is there a solution for this problem using HTAccess?
Best regards.